# No response or very late response from Lighttpd

Tags: plugins, module, webserver, lighttpd

I made a simple module for Lighttpd to experiment with it. If I just log on to the Ip address of my computer(from another computer) and the webserver(lighttpd) in my computer should send a simple response. The source code of the module is as below:

```
#include "base.h"
#include "log.h"
#include "buffer.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "plugin.h"
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "stat_cache.h"
#include "etag.h"
#include "http_chunk.h"
#include "response.h"
/* plugin config for all request/connections */


typedef struct {
    array *match;
} plugin_config;



typedef struct {
    PLUGIN_DATA;

    buffer *match_buf;

    plugin_config **config_storage;

    plugin_config conf;
} plugin_data;



typedef struct {
    size_t foo;
} handler_ctx;



static handler_ctx * handler_ctx_init() {
    handler_ctx * hctx;

    hctx = calloc(1, sizeof(*hctx));

    return hctx;
}



static void handler_ctx_free(handler_ctx *hctx) {

    free(hctx);
}

/* init the plugin data */
INIT_FUNC(mod_helloworld_init) {
    plugin_data *p;

    p = calloc(1, sizeof(*p));

    p->match_buf = buffer_init();

    return p;
}



/* detroy the plugin data */
FREE_FUNC(mod_helloworld_free) {
    plugin_data *p = p_d;

    UNUSED(srv);

    if (!p) return HANDLER_GO_ON;

    if (p->config_storage) {
        size_t i;

        for (i = 0; i < srv->config_context->used; i++) {
            plugin_config *s = p->config_storage[i];

            if (!s) continue;

            array_free(s->match);

            free(s);
        }
        free(p->config_storage);
    }

    buffer_free(p->match_buf);

    free(p);

    return HANDLER_GO_ON;
}



/* handle plugin config and check values */

SETDEFAULTS_FUNC(mod_helloworld_set_defaults) {
    plugin_data *p = p_d;
    size_t i = 0;

    config_values_t cv[] = {
    { "helloworld.array",NULL, T_CONFIG_ARRAY, T_CONFIG_SCOPE_CONNECTION},       /* 0 */
    { NULL, NULL, T_CONFIG_UNSET, T_CONFIG_SCOPE_UNSET }
    };

    if (!p) return HANDLER_ERROR;

    p->config_storage = calloc(1, srv->config_context->used * sizeof(specific_config *));

    for (i = 0; i < srv->config_context->used; i++) {
        plugin_config *s;

        s = calloc(1, sizeof(plugin_config));
        s->match    = array_init();

        cv[0].destination = s->match;

        p->config_storage[i] = s;

        if (0 != config_insert_values_global(srv, ((data_config*)srv->config_context->data[i])->value, cv)) {
            return HANDLER_ERROR;
        }
    }

    return HANDLER_GO_ON;
}

#define PATCH(x) \
    p->conf.x = s->x;
static int mod_helloworld_patch_connection(server *srv, connection *con, plugin_data *p) {
    size_t i, j;
    plugin_config *s = p->config_storage[0];

    PATCH(match);

    /* skip the first, the global context */
    for (i = 1; i < srv->config_context->used; i++) {
        data_config *dc = (data_config *)srv->config_context->data[i];
        s = p->config_storage[i];

        /* condition didn't match */
        if (!config_check_cond(srv, con, dc)) continue;

        /* merge config */
        for (j = 0; j < dc->value->used; j++) {
            data_unset *du = dc->value->data[j];

            if (buffer_is_equal_string(du->key, CONST_STR_LEN("helloworld.array"))) {
                PATCH(match);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
#undef PATCH

URIHANDLER_FUNC(mod_helloworld_uri_handler) {


UNUSED(p_d);

// Send body data to requestor
char buffer[] = { '<', 'h', 't', 'm', 'l', '>' , '<', 'h', 'e', 'a', 'd', '>', '<', 't', 'i', 't', 'l', 'e', '>', '1', '<', '/', 't', 'i', 't', 'l', 'e', '>', '<', '/', 'h', 'e', 'a', 'd', '>', '<', '/', 'h', 't', 'm', 'l', '>'};

    char textValue[32];
    sprintf(textValue, "%d", sizeof(buffer));

response_header_overwrite(srv, con, CONST_STR_LEN("Content-Length"), textValue, strlen(textValue));
chunkqueue_append_mem(con->write_queue, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); 

//
con->http_status = 200;
return HANDLER_FINISHED;

}


int mod_helloworld_plugin_init(plugin *p) {
    p->version     = LIGHTTPD_VERSION_ID;
    p->name        = buffer_init_string("helloworld");

    p->init        = mod_helloworld_init;
    p->handle_subrequest_start  = mod_helloworld_uri_handler;
    p->set_defaults  = mod_helloworld_set_defaults;
    p->cleanup     = mod_helloworld_free;

    p->data        = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

By using this module the web server should response with html page whose title is "1". But now I see that lighttpd is sending that respond very late, and as a result the request is sometimes timed out. I am not quite getting what's the problem. Could any body check and help me solve it? I guess only the users of Lighttpd may know the solution to this problem. Even without using Lighttpd if some one can help me solve this I'd appreciate that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
con->file_finished = 1;
```

after:

```
con->http_status = 200;
```

That tells the engine that the request is complete (why `HANDLER_FINISHED` doesn't do that is a question for another day).